# Win 7 How to Change Basic Theme Window Color?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, themes

In the Personalization control panel, when selecting the Windows 7 Basic theme (not Aero, and not classic), the windows have an Aero look but without any of the transparency effects.  Unfortunately, it looks like you can select any color you want, as long as it's baby boy blue.

Is there a way to make those windows another color?

The reason is that we're deploying thin clients connecting to a terminal server.  The computers have high visibility to the public and the blue clashes with our branding.  We can't use Aero because the server has no 3D graphics acceleration, and the classic theme looks like we're back in good ol' 1998.